# How can i write a sql statement to get customers who have rented at least one film from each category from dvdrental

Tags: sql-server, mysql, postgresql, azure-sql-database, pgadmin-4

How can i write a sql statement to get customers who have rented at least one film from each category, to Return customer_id, first_name and last_name. from dvdrental

Comment: 1. Please, pick single database engine. 2. Please, provide the definitions for the tables in question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i mean from postgreSQL, I want to query an SQL statement to get customers who have rented at least one film from each category on DVDrental

Answer (score -2):

```
DECLARE @DVDCategories TABLE (CategoryID INT IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key, CategoryName VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @DVDCategories (CategoryName)
VALUES ('Action'),('Drama'),('Documentories'),('Suspense')

DECLARE @Customer TABLE (CustomerID INT IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key, CustomerName VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @Customer (CustomerName)
VALUES ('Able'),('Bob'),('Charlie')

DECLARE @DVD TABLE (DVDID INT IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key, DVDName VARCHAR(50), DVDCategory INT)
INSERT INTO @DVD (DVDName, DVDCategory) 
VALUES ('Cain''s Altar',1),('That''s what she said!',2), ('But how!?',3),('Suddenly',4)

DECLARE @DVDRentals TABLE (DVD INT, Customer INT, RentalDate DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE())
INSERT INTO @DVDRentals (DVD, Customer)
SELECT DVDID, CustomerId
FROM @Customer C
CROSS JOIN @DVD D
WHERE C.CustomerID = 1
UNION
SELECT DVDID, CustomerId
FROM @Customer C
CROSS JOIN @DVD D
WHERE C.CustomerID = 2
    AND DVDID <> 2
UNION
SELECT DVDID, CustomerID
FROM @Customer C
CROSS JOIN @DVD D
WHERE D.DVDCategory <> 1

SELECT *
FROM @Customer C
WHERE C.CustomerID IN (
    SELECT Customer
    FROM (
    SELECT R.Customer, COUNT(DISTINCT DVDCategory) RentedCategories
    FROM @DVDRentals R
    JOIN @DVD D 
    ON D.DVDID = R.DVD
    GROUP BY R.Customer
    ) CustomerRentalCategoryCount
    WHERE RentedCategories = (
    SELECT COUNT(CategoryID)
    FROM @DVDCategories
    ) --TotalCategories
)
```